# How can an add-in detect when a solution is loaded?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How can my add-in detect when a solution is loaded?  I know there must be some event somewhere in the DTE model, but I can't find it.  My add-in loads when Visual Studio loads, but it depends on a solution being open.  I don't want to make it a solution add-in until MS loses their sick fixation on COM, as solution add-ins have to be COM components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to register for event handling using C#:

```
_solutionEvents = _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents;
_solutionEvents.Opened += new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(SolutionOpened);
_solutionEvents.AfterClosing += new _dispSolutionEvents_AfterClosingEventHandler(SolutionClosed);
```

Also note that when user opens Visual Studio by double clicking on a solution file, you won't get an event for solution opening. You should check whether _applicationObject.Solution is not null in OnStartupComplete method to handle this situation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The SolutionEvents class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutioneventsclass_events.aspx) includes event:

Opened: Occurs immediately after opening a solution or project.

Answer (score 0):

You have in the DTE2 class a property called `Events` it gives a lots kind of events, for what you need you have to use:

```
DTE2 _applicationObject
_applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents.Opened+=new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(SolutionEvents_Opened);
```