# Visual Studio On Solution Open Event

Tags: visual-studio

Is there an on solution open event in visual studio? Something similar to the Pre/Post build events for projects, but instead only fires when the solution opens. I would like to add a command to run when the solution opens, but can't seem to find anything that will allow me to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577877/how-can-an-add-in-detect-when-a-solution-is-loaded

Comment: Is there a way to tap into the solution open event without creating an add in?

Comment: What kind of action do you need to take when the solution opens ? Is it running a batch file or similar ? Or is it something more unique and bespoke to your organisation ?

Comment: a grunt command