# How to fetch the path of current solution opened in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, project-template, customtool

I created a tool window as part of VSIX project and installed an extension to test it. So, the tool window need access to the current solution/project opened in visual studio. When the user created the project for the first time, We can fetch the path using DTE object as mentioned in below and I tried them and it works fine,

[How can an add-in detect when a solution is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577877/how-can-an-add-in-detect-when-a-solution-is-loaded)

[Acessing currently opened solution in a vsix project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292155/acessing-currently-opened-solution-in-a-vsix-project)

But How to fetch the current solution path next time,when user just double clicks on solution? Right now when user opens the .sln file , the tool window breaks as it couldn't locate the opened solution path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user double-clicks and open the solution we do not have a `DTE` object in hand and we need a different way to get solutionInfo. I made it work using [IVsSolution.GetSolutionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.getsolutioninfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2019#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsSolution_GetSolutionInfo_System_String__System_String__System_String__)

```
IVsSolution solution = (IVsSolution) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsSolution));
solution.GetSolutionInfo(out string solutionDirectory, out string solutionName, out string solutionDirectory2);
var solutionPath = solutionDirectory + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(solutionName);
```